# Appendix with huge images causing blank pages

Tags: minipage, blank-page

What I'm trying to do is a document with two Appendix pages that are just holding a subsection headline and an (nearly fullscreen) image.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

  \subsection{A I - (XXX)}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[angle=90,origin=c,height=1\vsize]{img/a1.pdf}
  \end{minipage}


  \subsection{A II - (YYY)}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[angle=90,origin=c,height=1\vsize]{img/a2.pdf}
  \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

It's working kinda nice. The pages itself look like I want them to.

But its adding a blank page before each heading (What I'm getting is: blank, A I, blank, A II). Any ideas how to remove the blank pages? Are there any properties missing on the `minipage` ?

PS: the `subsection` doesn't cause any pagebreaks in the rest of the document

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You help us help you by adding a [Minimum Working (compiling) Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) showing the relevant packages you are using, that way more users will try and help you.

Comment: What happens if you change `height=1\vsize` to `height=0.9\textheight`?

Comment: thx for that, but it still causing this issue. (And the images are way smaller :/)

Comment: The problem is definetly because the images are crossing the margins of your document. Include in your preamble `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` and you'll see what I mean. Then, try to either make the Image fit the margins of your document or adjust the page layout to fit the image sized to your desire.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. Still a bit confusing that an large image that overlaps on the bottom/right side causes an blank page PRIOR the page. But downsizing of the images helps (but looks not so good) I guess I need to find an other approach. Thx so far ;)

Comment: you have specified that the image is the full height of the text block and (implictly) specified that no page breaks happen after section headings so latex has impossible constraints as it simply does not fit, the page break before the heading is it attempting to get a good break when it sees the heading plus the image do not fit. (the `minipage` is not doing anything here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[origin=c]` is unnecessary and somehow makes the height adjustment inaccurate.  Also, you can overlap the right margin with impunity using `\rlap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
  \subsection{A I - (XXX)}
  \noindent
  \rlap{\includegraphics[angle=90,height={\dimexpr\textheight-2\baselineskip}]{example-image-a}}

  \subsection{A II - (YYY)}
  \noindent
  \rlap{\includegraphics[angle=90,height={\dimexpr\textheight-2\baselineskip}]{example-image-b}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: great looking much better.